# Extract date from UUID in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, uuid

I am trying to decode uuid in mysql to identify what are the digits contributing to prepare the date part .
For e.g. `uuid ==> b54adc00-67f9-11d9-9669-0800200c9a66`

What is the date part in the above uuid.

Comment: Why do you assume that there's anything to do with a date in a UUID?

Comment: need to extract the date part only to see the count of records based on date

Comment: have i asked the wrong question?
I was reading this https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Comment: i am not very much sure ,instead of giving any explanation how someone can devote the questions just to increase their reputation.

Comment: downvoting decreases your reputation, not increases it.  I think this is from people who are unaware that (some types of) uuids have dates encoded in them.

Comment: @ysth or from people who think "this question does not show any research effort" (per the DV tooltip)

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
select  uuid                           AS uid
,       from_unixtime(
          (conv(                      
            concat(                   
              substring(uuid, 16, 3)
            , substring(uuid, 10, 4)
            , substring(uuid, 1, 8)
            ), 16, 10)                
            div 10 div 1000 div 1000  
          ) - (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60) 
        )                             AS uuid_to_timestamp
,       current_timestamp()           AS timestamp
from  test          ;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4uegQFAyd1NyuSme7F2JwX/1

Reference: https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-extracting-timstamp-and-mac.html?m=0

Comment: from_unixtime produces a time in the session timezone, so for timezones that observe daylight saving will have an ambiguous result some of the time

Comment: this is have already seen and trying over this.If you need to extract the dates only then how you will be doing it ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha i need only yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

This only works for variant 1 type uuids.  For the obsolete variant 0 or the rarely used variant 2, it would need modification, and other variants do not include dates; the variant is stored in the uuid (unless it is a fully random one) but I am not checking it.

Assuming uuid is the uuid in string form:

```
select '1582-10-15'
    + interval floor(
        conv(
            concat(
                substr(uuid,16,3),
                substr(uuid,10,4),
                substr(uuid,1,8)
            ),
            16,
            10
        )
        /1e7
    ) second
```

This produces a datetime in UTC; if you need it in your local timezone, convert it like:

```
convert_tz(
    '1582-10-15' + interval floor(conv(concat(substr(uuid,16,3),substr(uuid,10,4),substr(uuid,1,8)),16,10)/1e7) second,
    '+00:00',
    'America/Los_Angeles'
)
```

If you want just the date, wrap one of the above in `DATE( ... )`.

Comment: Great answer! (could probably stand to benefit from some newlines)